# jaxb xjc creating List< Objects > instead of List< String >

Tags: xsd, jaxb, schema, bind, xjc

I have an xsd like this -

```
<xs:element name="teachers" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="teacher" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When I use XJC to generate class bindings, I see teacher is of type - List < Object >  instead of List< String >

```
protected List<Object> teacher;
public List<Object> getTeacher() {
        if (teacher == null) {
            teacher = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.teacher;
    }
```

How can I make it to generate List of strings instead of objects? Any help is appreciated.

Update: With the solution provided by 'vamsilp' - After removing the "minOccurs" on "teachers" element, it worked just fine!That XSD is autogenerated by Jersey from this code:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "teachers")
@XmlElement(name = "teacher")
public StringSet getTeachers() {
    return getData().getTeacherss();
```

I am not sure how to remove the "minOccurs" attribute. Do I need to modify my code to ignore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I just dont understand how you are able to generate classes, instead it should show you an error saying "'minOccurs' cannot appear in element 'element'" because you have declared minOccur constraint to your global/root element "teachers". You shouldn't be doing that please refer [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-0-20041028/#Globals). Try regenerating your JAXB classes by removing this constraint that should work

Comment: Thank you so much! Strange but I am able to generate classes but they are malformed. Would you know how to ignore the "minOccurs" element from the autogenerated XSD? (Please check my update)

Comment: @keerthi: What do you mean by autogenerated XSD? I guess you mean the Autogenerated classes that you generate form the XSD? Also do you want to just remove the minOccurs constraint from the XSD? If that is the case just go ahead and delete that constraint and regenerate the classes, that should work fine. If not please clarify?

Comment: I have verified the generated classes by removing the "minOccurs" attribute manually and it worked fine. But the XSD is generated by Jersey for our REST app. I had copied (in my original description) a part of the code from which this XSD got generated.

Comment: @keerthi: Your question might receive better attention if you can post a fresh one under Jersey tag